# Software to duplicate external hard drive formatted ExFAT

Tags: hard-drive, partition, external-disk, exfat

I have an external hard drive with a 2.9TB ExFAT partition that I keep my photos and other media on. (ExFAT so that I can also see and edit my media on Windows computers.) I just bought a second hard drive that I will set up the same way so that I can back up my media. Normally, I use `SuperDuper!` but that only works with Mac formats. Is there any Mac or command line software that can check for exact duplication? Due to the size of the drive (2.9TB with 1.8TB used), I don't want to do the duplication manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have nothing on the *new* disk and essentially want to *mirror* what is on the *old* disk to the *new* disk.

You can use the following command line, substituting the proper names for *Source-Disk* (*old*) and *Destination-Disk* (*new*).

```
rsync -xavH /Volumes/Source-Disk/ /Volumes/Destination-Disk/
```

Note: The slash at the end of each path has significance, so don't forget to include it when changing the name of *Source-Disk* (*old*) and *Destination-Disk* (*new*).  Also, if there are spaces in them, make sure you either escape the spaces with a *backslash* `\` or quote the pathnames, but not both.

Explanation of the *options* used:

```
-x, --one-file-system    don't cross filesystem boundaries
-a, --archive    archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)

    -r, --recursive    recurse into directories
    -l, --links    copy symlinks as symlinks
    -p, --perms    preserve permissions
    -t, --times    preserve times
    -g, --group    preserve group
    -o, --owner    preserve owner (super-user only)
    -D    same as --devices --specials
        --devices    preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials    preserve special files

-v, --verbose    increase verbosity
-H, --hard-links    preserve hard links
```

Note: Because *symlinks* are being copied to the *Destination-Disk* volume the *volume name* of the *Destination-Disk* will need to be renamed identical to the *Source-Disk*, afterwards, for the *links* to files on the disk itself to track.  See the SYMBOLIC LINKS section in the `rsync` man page for additional *options* that can be used to modify how the *symlinks* can be treated.